# Unable to find mongodb.conf file on mongodb macports installation

Tags: mongodb, macports

I am new to Macports. I used macports to install mongodb. The only problem I have is I am unable to find the mongodb.conf file. I am a Ubuntu user and I know its located on /etc/mongodb.conf in Ubuntu. Where can I find it on my osx macports installation? I want to enable the --rest feature in the mongodb.conf file so that I can get the data from my web browser. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you won't find any *mongodb.conf* file with a 'port contents' because this is not macosx ways - you know: macs are "different" ...

Instead - assuming you did enable the mongodb launch agent that was created when you installed the mongodb port in the first place - you'll only have to edit THIS file as a text file:

```
/opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mongodb/org.macports.mongodb.plist
```

In the ProgramArguments array, add this below just before the semi-column string element:

```
<string>--rest</string>
```

If the macosx lauch agent was not activated yet you could still activate it yourself by creating a *symlink* like this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mongodb/org.macports.mongodb.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mongodb.plist
```

Next time you'll start mongodb its REST interface should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the files installed by a port with `port contents`:

```
port contents mongodb
```

You can `grep` the output for `mondgodb.conf` to find the location that it was installed.